# NatsError: stan: connect request timeout || port forwarding

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, nats-streaming-server

my publisher.ts file:

```
import nats from 'node-nats-streaming';

const stan = nats.connect('ticketing', 'abc', {
  url: 'http://localhost:4222',
});

stan.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Publisher connected to NATS');

  });
});
```

my port forwarding command:

```
kubectl port-forward {nats-deployment pod name} 4222:4222
```

my publish command in my nats-test folder:

```
"publish": "ts-node-dev --rs --notify false src/publisher.ts"
```

my nats-depl.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nats-depl
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nats
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nats
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nats
        image: nats-streaming:0.17.0
        args: [
          '-p',
          '4222',
          '-m',
          '8222',
          '-hbi',
          '5s',
          '-hbt',
          '5s',
          '-hbf',
          '2',
          '-SD',
          '-cid',
          '-ticketing'
        ]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nats-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: nats
  ports:
  - name: client
    protocol: TCP
    port: 4222
    targetPort: 4222
  - name: monitoring
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8222
    targetPort: 8222
```

not able to connect to nats client.

Comment: What does it mean: not able to connect to nats client? Do you have any erros, logs? Please describe what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the `connect` function is the **cluster ID**. You can check your **NATS cluster's ID** in the logs of the container where it is running. The cluster ID is underlined with green in the picture.

[image]

Thus, the `connect` function should be:

```
const stan = nats.connect('test-cluster', 'abc', {
  url: 'http://localhost:4222',
});
```

Instead of:

```
const stan = nats.connect('testing', 'abc', {
  url: 'http://localhost:4222',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your nats-depl.yaml file,
The last entry in your args array is -ticketing, which is your clusterId

remove **-** from **ticketing** entry

```
const stan = nats.connect('ticketing', 'abc', {
  url: 'http://nats-srv:4222', // nats-serv is your nats service name
});
```